# Where to find about arguments/options of Pantheon Terminal?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-terminal

Looking for this, that's not much to see:

```
 pantheon-terminal --help-all
[INFO 00:19:24.537835] Application.vala:155: Terminal version: 0.4.0.3
[INFO 00:19:24.537996] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-57-generic
[DEBUG 00:19:24.541766] Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.terminal.saved-state'
[DEBUG 00:19:24.545045] Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.terminal.settings'
Usage:
  pantheon-terminal [OPTION...] 

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

GTK+ Options
  --class=CLASS            Program class as used by the window manager
  --name=NAME              Program name as used by the window manager
  --gdk-debug=FLAGS        GDK debugging flags to set
  --gdk-no-debug=FLAGS     GDK debugging flags to unset
  --gtk-module=MODULES     Load additional GTK+ modules
  --g-fatal-warnings       Make all warnings fatal
  --gtk-debug=FLAGS        GTK+ debugging flags to set
  --gtk-no-debug=FLAGS     GTK+ debugging flags to unset

Application Options:
  -d, --debug              Enable debug logging
  -a, --about              Show About dialog
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

`--help-all` usually shows much more information in a terminal.

I have found on internet many options mentioned with the default terminal and at least `-e` works but is not mentioned. There must be others, but where to find about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a handy manpage for Terminal:

```
$ man pantheon-terminal

NAME
       pantheon-terminal - Modern terminal emulator from elementary project

       Pantheon  Terminal  is  a  beautiful and simple terminal emulator.  It's designed to be set up with sane
       defaults and little to no configuration and follows the elementary OS Human Interface Guidelines.

SYNOPSIS
       pantheon-terminal [OPTION...]

OPTIONS
       -h, --help
              Show help message and exit

       -v, --version
              Print version info and exit

       -e, --execute=PATH
              Execute the specified binary with given parameters in terminal.

       -w, --working-directory=PATH
              Set the specified directory as shell working directory on startup

AUTHOR
       Pantheon Terminal was written by Adrien Plazas <kekun.plazas@laposte.net>, Mario  Guerriero  <mario@ele‐
       mentaryos.org>,  David  Gomes  <david@elementaryos.org>,  Tom  Beckmann  <tom@elementaryos.org>,  Akshay
       Shekher <akshay@elementaryos.org> et al.

       This manual page was written by Sergey "Shnatsel" Davidoff  <sergey@elementaryos.org>,  for  the  Debian
       project (but may be used by others).

                                                  May 29, 2014                             pantheon-terminal(1)
```

Comment: that must be all then